# Correct CSP frame-src value for iframes with empty src value

Tags: security, request-headers

We have below CSP derivatives defined in our site,

```
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'  *.youtube.com; style-src  'self' 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *.facebook.com  www.youtube.com;
```

As per this value, we only allowed facebook, youtube domains as src value in our site iframes. But we have below iframes rendered in our site.

```
<iframe id="EPFACLC-1579856043157" src="about:blank" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" title="chat widget"></iframe>
```

How this iframes are not restricted by the CSP rule?

Thanks in advance.